# Keep getting Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, mysql

In my PHP code, I get this error on line 12 whenever I try to run it. (Code below ((obviously))

It tells me that mysql_fetch_object(): is not a valid MySQL result resource, but I have tried 4 PHP syntax checkers and all is well.

Thank you, and please help, thanks!

This is my code that I believe contains the error

```
<?
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'socialli_main2', 'password+',  `'socialli_main');
mysql_select_db(`Users`);
$ID = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET['ID'])));
$Username = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET['Username'])));
if (!$Username) {
$getUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID='".$ID."'");
}
else {
$getUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='".$Username."'");
}
$gU = mysql_fetch_object($getUser);
```

Comment: Can you tell me if there are any typos or anything in my code?
thanks

Comment: The linked answer tells you how to do some very basic debugging for mysql errors on your own – so please do that.

Comment: you have a typo on your first line in the end of mysql_connect

Comment: @user2896692: It's on the first line. Please **read** the entire line. We can't spoonfeed you. ;)

Comment: I found a random backtick at the end and removed, is that the error?

Comment: do you have a typo or is this the actual code you are showing?

Answer (score 0):

> $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'socialli_main2', 'password+',  **Here -->`**'socialli_main');
>   =)